# How can I extract dynamically generated data from graphs using Python?

Tags: python, dynamic, screen-scraping

Like the CodeChef's submission pie chart.

https://www.codechef.com/users/vishuvish

If I want to extract the number of solutions accepted, partially_solutions_accepted, etc. How can I do.
I have tried using PyQt4 but its not working.

Comment: It is just an html code. I don't think there is a simple solution except analysing the html code. On firefox, right click on "Inspect Element" and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Also it's not because the graph was generated from data in python that you can reverse the process back to python. Plotly or Bokeh are using some scripts in other languages to actually build the html graphs.

Comment: @Wli No its not just an html code.When you parse HTML of this page you will only get this.     `<section class="rating-data-section submissions">`
        `<h3>Submissions</h3>`
        `<div class="content">`
          `<div id="submissions-graph"></div>`
        `</div>`
      `</section><!--.submissions-->`.

Comment: I found the numbers you're searching by inspecting elements. In the source code of the page.